# Get time for yAxis

Tags: objective-c, algorithm

I'm trying to basically reverse this algorithm so that I get the time for a given y-Axis.

```
+ (CGFloat)yAxisForTime:(CGFloat)time
{
    CGFloat newTime = (float)(time * ((60 / [DataClass sharedInstance].timeInterval) / 2 ));
    return kTopBuffer + (44.0f * newTime);
}

+ (CGFloat)timeForYAxis:(CGFloat)y
{
    CGFloat newTime = (float)(y / ((60 * [DataClass sharedInstance].timeInterval) * 2 ));
    return kTopBuffer + (44.0f / newTime);
}
```

I have a brain fart today and can't seem to get it right. How would I get the time for yAxis? I have yAxisForTime working good, but now just need to get timeForYAxis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

```
y = kTopBuffer + (44 * newtime)
```

Then

```
newTime = (y - kTopBuffer) / 44
```

and therefore

```
time = (newTime / ((60 / [DataClass sharedInstance].timeInterval) / 2 ))
```

So:

```
time = ( ((y - kTopBuffer) / 44) / ((60 / [DataClass sharedInstance].timeInterval) / 2 ))
```

Comment: yeah, we all have them. no worries.